# Why is the UIButton larger than I set it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, constraints

I have a UIButton in my Xcode project that has constraints(see image #3). The height and width are both set to 80 but when I run the project it looks like bigger than what it is set to. (See image #2)

In the .m file, it is set 80x80 as well (objective-c)

```
openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 27, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 80, 80);
```

*It should look like:*

**Image #1**

[image]

**Image #2**

[image]

**Image #3**

[image]

Note: Those are the actual sizes (it is fit to scale)

**Why is it big like image #2 and how do I fix it so it stay 80x80 like image #1?**

Comment: trying to add hieght and width fix constraint hope this will help.

Comment: It worked, but please write it as an answer

Comment: @PHPWbDev101 i have added please check.

Comment: OH for that you want as an answer so can you accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying to add `hieght` and `width` fix **constraint** hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You should also set `width` and `height` constrains in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This will resize the button image to your desired size adding margins to it.

```
[openMenu setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25)];
```